# How to serialize an object to xml when a parent tag cannot appears in the result?

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to do serialize this class:

```
public class x
{
    public Y Value { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public string Value = "test";
}
```

but the expected result is:

```
<X>
    <Value>test</Value>
</X>
```

I can't show the `Y` tag, and can't modify my object. 
Has a way to do this ? Show the value from the object `Y` when serialize without modify the `VOs`?

Comment: Well you can do this really easily if you perform the serialization and deserialization manually... do you *need* to use the XML serializer? And when you say you can't modify your object - do you mean you can't change either of those classes *at all*?

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon, my object is really complex. This is only an example. And I can not change anything of the object, only attributes of xmlSerializer..

Comment: So you *can* add attributes to the class? (It's confusing when you talk about changing an *object* when you'd really be changing the *class*.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry the confusing.. I don't speak a good english.. I can not change the STRUCTURE of the class, but can add attributes of xmlserializer